# This logic puzzle is impossible!

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, liars

Rocks always tell the opposite of a statement and Rolls tell the truth.

If I was to tell you the following:

> - A says C is a roll.
> - A says there are 2 rocks.
> - B says they are a roll.
> - C says they are a roll.
> - C says B is a rock.

Then **who is a rock and who is a roll?**

Comment: Is a rock "the opposite" of a roll?

Comment: @JLee yes it would be - I should clarify everyone above is one or the other

Comment: Does A give two different statements, or a single statement containing an "and"?

Comment: @GregMartin both A and C should be treated as saying 2 different statements

Comment: Who is "they" in the 2nd and 3rd clues?

Comment: @TonyEnnis they is self referential here

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The trick to this puzzle is:

> The narrator is a liar!

Specifically,

> the given statements will always lead to a contradiction at face value. But assume for a moment that the narrator is someone who says opposites of statements (we'll not call them a Rock for reasons that will be clear soon).

Then the puzzle becomes:

> Rolls always tell the opposite of a statement, and Rocks tell the truth.
>
>  A says C is a rock.
>  A says there are 2 rolls.
>  B says they are a rock.
>  C says they are a rock.
>  C says B is a roll.
>
>  Then who is a roll and who is a rock?

Then there is a unique solution:

> A and C are both rocks, and B is a roll, and so is Beastly Gerbil. Indeed, A's statement checks out (C is a rock, and there are two rolls: B and Beastly Gerbil). B means to say they are a roll but says the opposite. C, again, tells the truth.

Lastly, the title:

> is, of course, the opposite of the truth, as expected from a roll: the puzzle is very much possible!

Comment: ok, ok, nice. i get it now, but my brain hurts. +1

Comment: It does not seem unique; what is wrong with only B being a rock?

Comment: @Retudin then A has to be a roll, but then there must be 2 rocks.

Comment: @Retudin if I've done everything correctly, this should be the unique answer, with everything else leading to paradox. Hopefully I haven't missed anything and that's the case!

Comment: OK I see my confusion; I consider the opposite "there must not be 2 rolls" Now the statement is effectively the same. But the rock-roll replacement is consistent; in my interpretation, the opposite of "A says X" would then also be "A does not say X". (I still wonder if there would be a better formulation) Nice one nonetheless!

Answer (score 4):

> I think the enigmatic part is whether Beastly Gerbil is a Rock or a Roll.

> Also assume the opposite of a statement is satisfied by swapping Rock and Roll in a statement.

> Assume BG is a Roll, and they are an honest narrator.

> If A is a Roll, then C is a Roll, B is a Rock, and A is a rock which is contradictory.

> Therefore, A is a Rock.

> Applying the opposite of a statement rule, A's true statement is
>  C is a Rock and that there are 2 Rolls.

> C is a Rock, A is a Rock, B is a Roll - But we need two Rolls.

> Therefore, Beastly Gerbil is a Rock and has be telling us the opposite all along.

So the puzzle becomes:

> Rolls always tell the opposite of a statement and Rocks tell the truth.

> If I was to tell you the following:

> >-   A says C is a Rock, and that there are 2 Rolls.
>  >-   B says they are a Rock.
>  >-   C says they are a Rock and that B is a Roll.

> Then **who is a rock and who is a roll?**

> >! If A is a Rock, then C is a Rock and we don't have room for two Rolls **** Wrong!  BG is a Roll now, so this could be correct  Will work through it later.****
> A is a Roll, and the truth is:
> C is a Roll and there are two Rocks

> B's statement does not contradict.

> Since C is a Roll, the true statement is:
>  C is a Rock and there are two rolls.

> So, B Rocks, and the others, including Beastly Gerbil, Roll.

Comment: If you want to nest formatting inside of spoilers, [use HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-support-block-formatting-and-so-dont-format-well).

Answer (score 2):

New Answer:
Notice that the puzzle's wording is

> "If I was to tell you the following: ... Then who is a rock and who is a roll?"

Therefore,

> since the puzzle is impossible, **you** are a rock!

---

Old Answer, not correct because of info I learned through comments below:
I think

> all three have to be rocks

Here are the possible outcomes for the 6 possibilities:

> A is a roll --> Rock, Rock, Roll
>  A is a rock --> Roll, Roll, Rock OR **Rock, Rock, Rock**
>  B is a roll --> ?, Roll, ?
>  B is a rock --> ?, Rock, ?
>  C is a roll --> Rock, Rock, Roll OR Roll, Rock, Roll
>  C is a rock --> Rock, Roll, Rock OR Roll, Roll, Rock

> If A is a roll, the only possible outcome is that A is a rock. That contradiction means A cannot be a roll, which means A must be a rock, which means all are rocks.

> So we have the answer already, but just to be thorough, let's look at whether can B be a roll. Since B claims to be a Roll, this contradicts A being a rock, which we already know, so B must also be a rock.

> Lastly, can C be a roll? No, because they claim that both they are a roll (false) AND that B is a rock (true). C being a roll would contradict A. Also note that a FALSE AND'ed with a TRUE is false, meaning that C must also be a rock.

Comment: note the enigmatic-puzzle tag.   I think there's more than just the straightforward analysis.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore yeah, good point. i totally missed that.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore is correct. The puzzle as the title suggests, *as it stands*, is literally impossible - and will always lead to contradiction. They can't all be rocks, as then C would be telling at least for the last half the truth...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Well, I thought that for an AND to be true, BOTH statements had to be true

Comment: Someone is not telling the truth here.  I think I know who it is.

Comment: @JLee I believe the intended parsing of C's line is "C says (they are a roll) and [C says] that (B is a rock.)": i.e. C makes two separate statements, the "and" being used to indicate that the same entity performs each action instead of creating logical linkage.

Comment: @bobble well, that totally destroys my angle, Bobble. thanks a lot!  haha jk

Comment: @bobble yep, sorry if thats bad grammar, but they're meant as separate statements!

Answer (score 2):

A and C are both rolls (truth tellers), and B and D (who didn't say anything) are rocks (liars).

So now A's statement is true, B's statement is false, and C's statement is true - and all statements are consistent.

Thus, Beastly Gerbil must also be a rock, as the title of the post is false - presumably s/he is the D who doesn't make a statement.